# Passing parameters in generically implement methods in hashmap

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, reflection, hashmap

I am following this question 
[How to generically implement calling methods stored in a HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063522/how-to-generically-implement-calling-methods-stored-in-a-hashmap)
I am trying to pass parameters while calling `executeCommand`
function 
Example code is as follows, 
**InvokesMethodItf**

```
public interface InvokesMethodItf {

public void invokeMethod(String data) throws Exception; //pass the data as parameter
public void setMethod(Method method);
}
```

**InvokesMethod**

```
public class InvokesMethod implements InvokesMethodItf{

private Method method;

@Override
public void invokeMethod(String data) throws Exception {
     method.invoke(data);    //pass the data to invoke (I think my problem is here). I dont know how to pass it.
}

@Override
public void setMethod(Method method) {
    this.method = method;
}

}
```

**Terminal**

```
public class Terminal {

public HashMap<Character, InvokesMethodItf> commands;

public Terminal() {
    this.commands = new HashMap<Character, InvokesMethodItf>();


}


private void setCommand(char letter, Method method) {

    InvokesMethodItf inv = new InvokesMethod();

    inv.setMethod(method);

    this.commands.put(letter, inv);
}

public void executeCommand(char letter, String data) throws Exception {
    this.commands.get(letter).invokeMethod(data);    //pass data to invoke method
 }
}
```

**Main**

```
    public class Main {           

    Terminal commandLine = new Terminal();
    commandLine.setCommand('h',test());   //This should give syntax error or i am not sure
    commandLine.executeCommand('h', "This is a test");

   public Method test(String data){
        Log.d("Test", data);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I am trying to set multiple methods using setCommand and execute it.

```
commandline.setCommand('p',this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("parseData",String.class,Integer.class), this);
commandline.setCommand('p', this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("test"), this);
```

Then , calling

```
commandline.executeCommand('p', "test", 2345);
```

Only test function is calling.(Last setCommand function is running). I think it is overwriting `Method` . Isn't there is someway to pass multiple methods in setCommand function.  Changing type of `Method` to `Method[]` is not working either.

Comment: When invoking a method, you also need to pass the instance holding the method you want to invoke: `method.invoke(instance, params)`. See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Comment: For static method use `null` as instance

Comment: @talex test is not a static method

Comment: @sp00m can you give more insight about the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking a method, you need to pass the instance from which the method should be invoked as well as the parameters:

```java
public interface MethodInvoker {

    // the method + the instance from which the method should be called
    public void setMethod(Method method, Object instance);

    // invokes the method
    public void invoke(Object... params) throws Exception;

}
```

Here an implementation:

```java
public class MethodInvokerImpl implements MethodInvoker {

    private Method method;
    private Object instance;

    @Override
    public void setMethod(Method method, Object instance) {
        this.method = method;
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(Object... params) throws Exception {
        // first param: instance, then the parameters
        method.invoke(instance, params);
    }

}
```

Then your Terminal:

```java
public class Terminal {

    public Map<Character, MethodInvoker> commands;

    public Terminal() {
        commands = new HashMap<Character, MethodInvoker>();
    }

    // instance needed, since MethodInvoker#setMethod needs it
    public void addCommand(char letter, Method method, Object instance) {
        MethodInvoker invoker = new MethodInvokerImpl();
        invoker.setMethod(method, instance);
        commands.put(letter, invoker);
    }

    public void executeCommand(char letter, Object... params) throws Exception {
        commands.get(letter).invoke(params);
    }

}
```

Finally in your main:

```java
public void test(String data) {
    System.out.println(data);
}

public void main() throws Exception {
    Terminal commandLine = new Terminal();
    // #text() will be called from "this" instance
    commandLine.addCommand('h', getClass().getMethod("test", String.class), this);
    commandLine.executeCommand('h', "This is a test");
}
```

---

Note that static methods don't need instances since they belong to the class, e.g.:

```java
public void main() throws Exception {
    Terminal commandLine = new Terminal();
    // simply pass "null" as instance
    commandLine.addCommand('h', getClass().getMethod("test", String.class), null);
    commandLine.executeCommand('h', "This is a test");
}

public static void test(String data) {
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

---

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/542122/1225328 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348228/1225328 as well.

Comment: Thanx , i have one small doubt in getClass().getMethod("test", String.class) . Suppose , in my main activity i declare the test function normally . If i use  getClass().getMethod("test", String.class) in some other scope,lets say i created the interface and use addCommand in that override function. It is catching this error java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: test [class java.lang.String]

Comment: i did some debugging turns out  getClass().getMethod("test", String.class) .checks the function in same scope(not global).

Comment: @Neil `getClass()` returns the class of `this`. In my example, if `main()` is in class `MyMain` for example, `getClass()` will equal `MyMain.class` (unless it has been instantiated via a subclass). That is to say, if you want to call the method `AnyClass#anyMethod(String, Integer)`, then use `AnyClass.class.getMethod("anymethod", String.class, Integer.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Method` is an `Object` which you will have to get using `reflection`.As I see the problems in your code,you cannot get `Method` Object using method `invocation`.Change this in your `Main` class.Check the **javadoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...))**  for getting `Method` `Object` from `Class` `Object`(for class Object you can use `Class.forName(String class_binary_name)` or `Class literal`

```
   public class Main {           

        Terminal commandLine = new Terminal();
        Method method = Main.class.getMethod("test",String.class);
        commandLine.setMethod('h',method); 
        commandLine.executeCommand('h', "This is a test");

        public void test(String data){
            Log.d("Test", data);

        }
    }
```

Also,change the return type of test class to void if you are not planning to return anything

Comment: I tried the same code. Nothing is getting print in log. App is running fine. 09-29 15:10:18.873: W/System.err(1818): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type com.example.hello.MainActivity, but got java.lang.String
09-29 15:10:18.883: W/System.err(1818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 15:10:18.903: W/System.err(1818):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
Getting these system errors. I think problem is in method.invoke() function.