# Executable method into hashtable as value

Tags: android, methods, hashtable, text-to-speech

I'm using TTS in my app. I want to run a method when I ask for it. I created a `Hashtable` where I want to store my methods like:

```
table.put("qqq", say("www"));
```

I'm comparing my data with keys - it works, but it does not trigger a method.

This probably isn't possible with `Hashtable`, so please tell me how to do what I want in the simplest way

Comment: You can store instances or types, e.g., an instance of an interface that has a `say` method. Look for "command pattern in Java" or something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a method stored in a HashMap? (Java)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480334/how-to-call-a-method-stored-in-a-hashmap-java)

Answer (score 1):

You should save the `Object` which calls that method:

```
Hashtable<String, MyObject> objects = new Hashtable<String, MyObject>();
objects.put("qqq",new MyObject());

MyObject test = objects.get("qqq");
test.say("www");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `java.lang.reflect`, might be the right thing to use in your situation.
With reflection you can do something like this:

```
Method method = myObject.getClass().getMethod("say", String.class);
method.invoke(myObject, "www");
```

So all you would need to do is store the object, method name, and parameters and then you can dynamically invoke the method.

Answer (score 0):

probably it is more a design issue.

**Solution could be**: if You are using only `say()` method, then store just a parameter that You would pass to the `say()` method (E.g., `table.put("qqq", "www");`). And when You need particular phrase to be found just call `say(table.get("qqq"));`.

Comment: I'm not using only this method... I have ~50 differents methods ;/