# Routing intents in a IntentService

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The method I have seen for routing intents to their handling methods in an intent service is usually like the following:

```
 if (action.equals(Constants.INTENT_UPDATE)) {
        handleUpdate(intent);
 } else if(action.equals(Constants.INTENT_UPDATE)) {
        handleUpdate(intent);
 }
 ...
```

This could be improved slightly by adding a switch statement, but I am wondering if there is a better method for routing intents in an intent service. I come from a Java web background and I  am use to either using annotations or having some type of mapping file whereas using if/else blocks is harder to read and grows pretty ugly when you have numerous intents (in my case over 20).

I have also considered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480334/how-to-call-a-method-stored-in-a-hashmap-java) on how to map to methods via a Map, though I feel that makes it just more convoluted.

Comment: Downvoter, is it unclear what I am asking or is there another reason?

Comment: Can `handleUpdate()` be declared as static? Meaning, does it use any member variables?

Comment: @Emmanuel yes it can be static, there are no member variables used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the [`Command`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern. Basically you create a class that implements an interface that has an `execute()` that the `IntentService` will call. Make sure that each of the classes that implement `Command` also implement `Parcelable` so you can send the `Command` implementation with the `Intent`. The idea is to be able to do something like this in your `IntentService`:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public MyIntentService(){
    super("Service Name");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
        Command command = (Command)intent.getParcelableExtra("command");
        command.execute();

    }

}
```