# In Java, how do I create a List of function pointers which take an argument each?

Tags: java, function-pointers

I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480334/how-to-call-a-method-stored-in-a-hashmap-java), that works for an argument less method list containing Runnables. I need to have `Consumer` in my case. This is what I have so far:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class experiment {

 private static List<Consumer<String>> activities;

 public experiment (){
 activities = ImmutableList.of(
     (userId) -> this::bar,        // throws error
     (userId) -> this::foo);
 }

 public void bar(String x) {
   System.out.println(x);
 }

 public void foo(String x) {
   System.out.println(x);
 }

 public static void main(String []args) {

  for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    activities.get(i).accept("activity #" + i);
  }
 }
}
```

The error I see is `void is not a functional interface`.

I don't understand why I'm getting that, both `bar` and `foo` implement the accept method of the Consumer interface. Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Java doesn't have functions pointers, its lambda or method references

Comment: Unconditionally initializing a static field in the constructor is very bad logic. Either initialize in a static initializer block, or change field to non-static.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you want to write `ImmutableList.of(this::bar, this::foo)` instead of `ImmutableList.of((userId) -> this::bar, (userId) -> this::foo)`.

If you do want to use lambdas instead of method references, you should instead write `ImmutableList.of((userId) -> this.bar(userId), (userId) -> this.foo(userId))`.

Comment: Nice and concise answer. Of course, once these changes are applied and the code compiles, the next problem is NPE caused by `activities` being null.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda's are wrong. You either supply a method reference, *or* you supply a lambda expression. You're trying an incorrect combo.

Also, your two methods `foo()` and `bar()` should be `static`, and your instance variable should not be. To show how instance methods could be called, I've added `baz()` and `qux()`.

Here's showing full example:

```
public class Experiment {

    private List<Consumer<String>> activities;

    public Experiment() {
        this.activities = ImmutableList.of(
            (userId) -> Experiment.bar(userId),
            Experiment::foo,
            (userId) -> this.baz(userId),
            this::qux
        );
    }

    public static void bar(String x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void foo(String x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void baz(String x) {
        System.out.println(this.hashCode() + ": " + x);
    }

    public void qux(String x) {
        System.out.println(this.hashCode() + ": " + x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Experiment ex = new Experiment();
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.activities.size(); i++) {
            ex.activities.get(i).accept("activity #" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The methods don't _have_ to be static, but it'd probably make sense for them to be.

Comment: @LouisWasserman and Andreas, Why do you 2 recommend them to be static? In my case, the functions are instance specific and reference a bunch of instance variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: Sure, then they can be instance methods.  activities should be an instance variable too, though.

Comment: @Siddhartha We can only recommend things based on what you show. Static field initialized by constructor is bad and needed to be addressed. Using an instance method reference to a method that doesn't have any instance logic needed a comment about better usage. The lack of invoking the constructor was really bad, and was really unrelated to question, but you included `main()` method for a reason, so needed to be addressed.