# Java 8 - Nested if inside a loop

Tags: java-8, java-stream

So I have a list and for each item in the list I have to "do something" based on each list element.

The list consists of codes and there are a total of 5 codes. The list may contain any or all codes.

So far I've used the forEach and i've written the if conditions inside it as below -

```
List<Category> categories = getCategories();

categories.stream().forEach(category -> {
            if(category.equals(Category.A)) {
                // do something
            } else if(category.equals(Category.B)) {
                // do something
            } else if(category.equals(Category.C)) {
                // do something
            } else if(category.equals(Category.D)) {
                // do something
            } else if(category.equals(Category.E)) {
                // do something
            }
        });
```

I'm looking at refactoring this. Can someone please look at how better this can be done?

Comment: You could put `// do something` inside a method `void doSomething()` that every Category overwrites and then simply write `category.doSomething()`.

Comment: Create a loopkup table. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480334/how-to-call-a-method-stored-in-a-hashmap-java) for info.

Comment: What kind of comparison is `category.equals(Category.A)`?

Comment: @luk2302 maybe write an answer?

Comment: The stream creation is not necessary here, either. The Collection interface has a forEach method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, do not use multiline lambdas and create new method (with *switch*):

```
private void doSomethingBasedOnCategory(Category category) {
    switch(category) {
        case A: // do something
                break;
        case B: // do something
                break;
        case C: // do something
                break;
        case D: // do something
                break;
        case E: // do something
                break;
    }
}
```

Then use it in your lambda:

```
getCategories()
    .stream()
    .forEach(category -> doSomethingBasedOnCategory(category);
```

Another way is to create static *map* prefilled with keys (which will be Category.X) and values (which will be functions ready to use)

Comment: Could also use method reference `this::doSomethingBasedOnCategory`

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I would improve is to use a switch-statement:

```
switch(category){    
   case Category.A:
        // do Something
   break;
}
```

As mentionend by luk2302 this will only work if Category is an enum.

Comment: what if `Category` is simply a regular class, not an enum!?

Comment: Then it won't work I guess. The Author didn't really provide this info. It's worth a try.

Comment: Category is an Enum so this will work. I was going to use either the nested if or switch but the reason I asked this was to see if there was any possibility of using lambda functions to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `doSomething` method to the `Category` class and simply call it in the `.forEach`.

For example:

```
public class Category {

    // any other methods/variable/constructors

    public void doSomething() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
categories.stream().forEach(Category::doSomething);
```

If the `// do something` has not a common behaviour, you can move the if part inside the `doSomething` method.

Comment: Category is an enum. I could write the login in the enum class but I would want to keep the logic separate. This would've definitely been my implementation if it was a class. thanks!